# Using PCL with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, include, cmake, point-cloud-library

I built a PCL under windows using cmake. And when I use it in my own project, I need to add the additional include folder. But I couldn't find where is the include folder.

There is one folder named as "include" under the main PCL folder, but there is only one file in it, that is "pcl_config.h".

Does this mean there is any problem with my own built library?

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you didn't build all the components. This is what I see with my 1.6 all in installation with prebuilt binaries: (I don't have enough reputation to post images)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjxgC.png

Inside each folder you have several .h files.